# Power series expansion in terms of a function

Tags: series-expansion, functional

I have a two variable function `z[x,y] = f[x,y] + g[x,y]`, such that I know the functional form of `f[x,y]` but not of `g[x,y]`. I have to do some symbolic calculations with the function `z[x,y]`, but I would like to keep only the first order in `g[x,y]` (treating `g` as small). So, for example, I would like Mathematica to approximate `(z[x,y])^3 = (f[x,y] + g[x,y])^3 = f[x,y]^3 + 3*f[x,y]^2*g[x,y]`, or `(D[z[x,y], x])^2  = (D[f[x,y], x])^2 + 2*D[f[x,y], x]*D[g[x,y], x]`. Is there a way to do it? I have tried the most naive way, namely to use `Series['exp'[z],{g, 0, 1}]`, treating `g[x,y]` as a parameter rather than a function, but (as expected) it doesn't work. Do you know a way to do it?

Thank you very much in advance for anyone who will reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a simple approach which assumes `g and its derivatives(!)` to be small:

```
z[x,y]:= f[x,y]+eps g[x,y]

Normal[Series[(f[x, y] + eps g[x, y])^3, {eps, 0, 1}]] /. eps -> 1
(*f[x, y]^3 + 3 f[x, y]^2 g[x, y]*)

Normal[Series[D[z[x, y] ^2, x], {eps, 0, 1}]] /. eps -> 1
(*2 f[x, y] Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] + 2 g[x, y] Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] + 2 f[x, y] Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y]*)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @PPIP You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`O`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/O.html) to drop higher-order terms:

```
Clear[f, g, z]
z[x_, y_] := f[x, y] + g[x, y]

z[x, y]^3 + O[g[x, y]]^2
```

[image: series expression still containing O]

If you want an expression without the `O`, use `Normal`:

```
z[x, y]^3 + O[g[x, y]]^2 // Normal

(* Out: f[x, y]^3 + 3 f[x, y]^2 g[x, y] *)
```

This works for the derivative as well:

```
D[z[x, y], x]^2 + O[g[x, y]]^2 // Normal // Expand

(* Out:
   Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y]^2 + 
     2*Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] * Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y] + 
       Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y]^2
*)
```

Comment: Nice idea !   For the derivative I would expect a result without the last part `Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y]^2`

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something that automatically neglects also the last term in the derivative, as Ulrich said, but your insight was very useful as well!